# how to collect a specific prometheus metric from replicated containers and get average of them

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, docker-swarm

I have a container named `downloader` and scaled it into 3 containers.

I am using [prometheus python client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python), and in each container have a [Gauge](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#gauge) metric called `Rate`.

This `Rate` metric is separately accessible through internal port `8000` of each container.I mapped these 3 internal port to range `8000-8002` of external port.

[image]

what I want is that I want to get **Average** of these 3 `Rate` and show this average in Grafana panel as a single item.

I think I should change `prometheus/prometheus.yml` file, but not sure what is the case. any idea could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you redirect the 3 prometheus instances to the port `8000` do you have 3 different metrics available? For instante, `metric_rate_01`, `metric_rate_02`, and `metric_rate_03`?

Comment: yes, each container have a metric called `Rate`. but each one is available on different port. One `Rate` is available on port `8000` another one is on port `8001` and last one is available on port `8002`

Comment: Prometheus is not a distributed storage. So either you try to aggregate your metrics in grafana using different sources or you use https://thanos.io/ to aggregate them in a centralized "prometheus".